# export database to another server mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export database from Sever A to server B. I am using following command

```html
$ mysqldump -u user -p'password' db-name foo | ssh user@remote.box.com mysql -u user -p'password' db-name foo
```

When i run command in powershell then it prompt password again. although i am passing password in my commmand.. is there any way to bypass the password prompt?

Comment: There  must be a space between -p & password.

Comment: unclear is why `db-name` and `foo`+

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth same results.. i think he asking for ```SSH``` user password. can we bypass it?

Comment: @danblack ```foo```is a tabel name

Comment: right. but it shouldn't be on the mysql side.

Comment: ok i will remove it.. But actual problem is "how to bypass password".

Answer (score 0):

a) You can remove the password for the account user.

b) You can use a [unix socket authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) for the user to not require a password but still be the user (requires unix and mysql user to be identically named).

c) you can use ~/.my.cnf to contain a password [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)/

```
[client]
password=....
```

Comment: on which server we should make .my.cnf file ??? on master or slave ???